# Spring MVC table blob field to json

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, blob

I have a blob field in the database table. It contains specific information. I need to pass the data from this field to Rest as json. Rest uses Spring MVC.

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/blob", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, produces = "application / json; charset = utf-8")
```

To transfer the blob, I came up with a transformation to String, the client from String will again get byte [] and read it.

Here is my query and set transformer.

```
Query <?> Q = session.createNativeQuery (sql);
q.setReadOnly (true);
q.setResultTransformer (BasicTransformerAdapterBlob.INSTANCE);
list = q.getResultList ();
```

Transformation class code

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils;
import org.hibernate.transform.BasicTransformerAdapter;

public class BasicTransformerAdapterBlob extends BasicTransformerAdapter {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public final static BasicTransformerAdapterBlob INSTANCE;
    static {
        INSTANCE = new BasicTransformerAdapterBlob();
    }

    private BasicTransformerAdapterBlob() {

    }

    @Override
    public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++) {
            Object t = tuple[i];
            if (t != null && t instanceof Blob) {
                Blob b = (Blob) tuple[i];
                try {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    IOUtils.copy(b.getBinaryStream(), bos);
                    t = new String(bos.toByteArray(),"UTF-8");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            map.put(aliases[i], t);
        }
        return map;
    }

}
```

As a result, I get Json

```
[ {
  "LINE_ID" : 1,
  "LINE_NAME" : "My line",
  "COORDS" : "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000ЂЋ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 Pе@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000ИЌ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000@Mе@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000`Ќ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000`Iе@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000pЊ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000аDе@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000ё‹\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000`?е@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�Љ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000@8е@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000А‰\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000а1е@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\b‰\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000,е@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0018€\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000А%е@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Ђ‡\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u001Fе@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000А†\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000А\u0018е@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\b†\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Ђ\u000Fе@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000p…\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Ђ\u0007е@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u00008…\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 \u0002е@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000и„\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Ђэд@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000ё„\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000ашд@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000р„\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000`сд@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000x…\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000лд@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Ё…\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 ед@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0018†\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 ад@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 †\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000АЪд@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000@‡\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Фд@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000ш‡\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 Од@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 ‰\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 Жд@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000ЂЉ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 їд@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 ‹\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000А№д@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Ќ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Ђід@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 Ћ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000®д@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000ЂЏ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000©д@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Ёђ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000¤д@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000и‘\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000@ д@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000x“\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000аљд@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\b•\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000`•д@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000°–\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Ађд@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000x�\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000‹д@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Ёљ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000А„д@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000pњ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000@д@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Иќ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Ђ{д@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000pџ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000wд@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000Ў\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000`rд@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000рЎ\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000аoд@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000аў\tA\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000mд@"
} ]
```

It turns out that some characters are transmitted as � and the client can not decrypt them.

How can this be fixed?

What other mechanism is there to transfer the blob field to json?

Comment: the best way to exchange byte in string should be to use [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Answer (score 1):

Base 64 Representation can be used in this case. Convert your `BLOB`  data into Base64 string and then pass to client. Any client can decode it and use it easily.

And if you are using **Java 8** then you have [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class directly available into package:

```
import java.util.Base64;
```

And your code for encoding into Base64 will change to :

```
public String encodeBase64(byte [] encodeMe){
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(encodeMe);
    return new String(encodedBytes) ;
    }
```

and similarly your new decoding will change as

```
public byte[]decodeBase64(String encodedData){
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedData.getBytes());
    return decodedBytes ;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an alternative. But there is still a question. SQLDeveloper correctly saves this blob field to text UTF-8. Is it possible to repeat how it is done in SQLDeveloper?

Comment: Have u tried converting this data using query like  'SELECT CONVERT(column USING utf8) AS DecodedData FROM table';